# How to convert Stream<T?> to Stream<T>

Tags: dart, option-type

I have the following function that will return `int?` by accepting `String`.

```dart
int? convert(String s) {
  // Some implementation
}
```

Then I have this function that will convert a `Stream<String>` to `Stream<int>`. My current implementation looks like the following.

```dart
Stream<int> convertStream(Stream<String> s) {
  return s
    .map<int?>((i) => convert(i))
    .where((i) => i!=null)
    .map<int>((i) => i!);
}
```

This way doesn't look nice to me. Is there any other way that can be used to achieve the same behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Unlike `Iterable`, `Stream` doesn't have a `whereType` method. So you can't do `s.map(convert).whereType<int>()`.

You can replace `.map<int>((i) => i!)` by `.cast<int>()`.

Alternativelly you can use an `async*` method:

```
Stream<int> convertStream(Stream<String> input) async* {
  await for (var s in input) {
    var i = convert(s);
    if (i != null) {
      yield i;
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: As suggested by @lrn you can also use `expand`:

```
stream.expand<int>((int? v) => v == null ? [] : [v])
```

Comment: With some slight changes, you could change `convertStream` to a `whereType<R>` extension on `Stream<T>`.

Comment: Oneliner: `stream.expand<int>((int? v) => v == null ? [] : [v])`.

Comment: `whereType` is available in `rxdart`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `whereType<T>()` in the [stream_transform](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform) Dart dev package, like so:

```
import 'package:stream_transform/stream_transform.dart';

Stream<int> convertStream(Stream<String> s) {
  return s
    .map<int?>((i) => convert(i))
    .whereType<int>(); // <--
}
```